# Как грамотно организовать обновление базы данных

Tags: android, app

Android-app работает с базой данных, она изначально лежит на сервере, довольно тяжёлая и при первом запуске качается полностью (для возможности обращения к данным в offline и экономии траффика)... Каким образом организовать её обновление, чтобы каждый раз не перекачивать заново?
Добавить построчные контрольные суммы в каждую таблицу и возвращать только изменённые данные для апдейта? Или может велосипед давно изобретён?

Comment: контрольные суммы особо ничего не дадут, их же придется все сверять. Проще при каждом обновлении записи менять в ней поле с датой модификации. Клиент при запросе данных должен только сообщить максимальное время, которое он видел. А сервер возвращает все, что новее. Отдельно понадобится список удаленных записей, так же с датами

Comment: Можно еще использовать реплицируемую бд. Couchdb, mongodb, realm и возможно т.д. может так будет проще....

Answer (score 2):

Тут два основных подхода:

1. Тот, что уже описали в комментарии, с добавлением поля со временем последнего изменения в каждую строку. Но это дороговато по памяти может быть, и нужно скорее для очень активно изменяющейся базы. Вместо времени можно использовать номер операции. То есть первая добавленная запись помечается 1. Вторая получает 2. Затем меняем первую - она становится 3 и т.д. Если операции происходят реже, чем раз в миллисекунду - такой подход выгоднее
2. Если база обновляется не пару тысяч раз в день, а, скажем, вы раз в день/неделю/месяц выкладываете новую версию, то пилите систему контроля версий. Для каждого перехода с n на n+1 готовите скрипт/еще одну базу, которая содержит разницу. Клиент видит, что у него 8, а на сервере есть 10. Он качает скрипты для перехода с 8 на 9 и с 9 на 10, выполняет последовательно и получает актуальные данные. Можно еще запарится и готовить для каждой новой версии все возможные скрипты перехода, то есть для 10 версии делаем отдельно 9->10, 8->10,7->10...1->10, но профитность такого подхода в большинстве случаев весьма спорная

Comment: Система контроля версий в моём случае, думаю, излишне... Хоть данныи и не будут обновляться часто. Первое мне больше нравится, но нам придётся данные не удалять, а помечать на удаление, для возможности синхронизации и так же при этом наращивать индекс? т.е. будет захламляться излишними данными?

Comment: В общем случае да, хотя возможно присылать с сервера список удаленных данных, но это тоже больно станет со временем, если количество удаленных записей окажется больше существующих. Мне кажется вы не совсем верно оценили сложности реализации, второй вариант однозначно проще в реализации и допускает серьезные изменения структуры бд. Если однажды в схеме бд что-то меняется вы можете "продублировать" инструмент по работе с ней и научит программу открывать бд нужной версией инструмента, тем самым довольно безболезнено переводя клиентов на новую версию. С метками это будет куда сложнее